# Initializing the derivative of a state variable during process simulation

Tags: gekko

When simulating a process using GEKKO (for example, as in Example 15 [here](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization)), how would I set the initial value of the derivative of a state variable? I am using IMODE=4, but I could also use IMODE=7.

[Edit] I have fitted the parameters of a ODE-model with measured input and output using IMODE=5 and I would like to predict model output beyond measured time points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of Problem 8 from that same link as a simple example. To initialize the derivative, create a new variable such as `dydt` and define a new equation that is equal to the derivative.

[image: Problem 8]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

m = GEKKO()
k = 10
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)

y = m.Var(value=5)
dydt = m.Var(value=0)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)
m.Equation(k*dydt==-t*y)
m.Equation(dydt==y.dt())
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(m.time,y.value,label='y')
plt.plot(m.time,dydt.value,label='dy/dt')
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend(); plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

Unlike other differential algebraic equation (DAE) solvers, Gekko does not require consistent initial conditions for the states and derivatives. Gekko can also [solve higher-index DAEs](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/PendulumMotion) where the index is the number of times that constraints must be differentiated to return to ODE form.